# iPhone web app icon: Force native Safari to load (like Grooveshark)

Tags: iphone, web, homescreen

Our iPhone web app has a homescreen icon users can save.  It's an audio specific application.

When users save it to their homescreen and then click homescreen icon, the iPhone doesn't open regular Safari.  Rather it opens some sort of quasi Safari, one where there is no URL bar to be seen.  Actually it's really cool and makes our web app feel a lot like a native app.  Unfortunately this version of Safari doesn't play audio when user has their phone sounds off.  Regular Safari will play sounds either way.

Thus and like Grooveshark has done we want when user clicks our web app icon to open regular Safari.

Can anyone provide any guidance on this?

Answer (score 1):

If it's opening a standalone application you have to remove the web-app-capable from your meta tags.

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

[More informations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html)

Comment: thanks... actually you need to change content = "yes"  to "no"

Comment: Well, if you don't need it you can just make your file lighter.